# Android SDK app should ask login only for first time

Tags: android, sdk

I am Android developer, I am using Salesforce SDK for android to connect with Salesforce data.

I need to develop time punches app, In this user can punch in and punch out. In this case Android App should not logout after login.

But, In salesforce SDK some times asking login. How can we restrict logout..? that means App should ask for login only first time. it should not logout except we do manually.